# How to ignore a relationship in a tabular model

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular

I have an issue that I can't explain. Consider the following DAX measure:

```
Actual Spend :=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Finance Actuals'[Amount] ),
    FILTER (
        ALLSELECTED ( 'Finance Period' ),
        'Finance Period'[Fiscal_Date_Key] <= MAX ( 'Finance Period'[Fiscal_Date_Key] )
    ),
    FILTER (
        'Finance Actuals',
        'Finance Actuals'[Calculated_Date_Key]
            <= MAX ( 'Finance Forecasting Period'[Calculated_Date_Key] )
    ),
    ALL ( 'Finance Calculated Data Snapshot Date' )
)
```

There is a relationship between 'Finance Actuals' and 'Finance Calculated Data Snapshot Date'. For the purpose of this measure I want to ignore that relationship and use a pre-defined date selected in a different table ('Finance Forecasting Period').

Everything is working except that the measure is still being affected by changes to 'Finance Calculated Data Snapshot Date'. I would have expected that adding the ALL ( 'Finance Calculated Data Snapshot Date' ) portion of the measure should have caused changes to that table to be ignored.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CALCULATE` function will apply its filters using `AND` logic. I'm guessing what is happening is that that relationship is being used inside the `FILTER` function on `'Finance Actuals'` and adding the `ALL` function doesn't change anything.

Try moving the `ALL` function inside your second `FILTER` function since that's where it needs to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alexis.

I'm not quite sure how to add the `ALL` into the second filter as defined, as they relate to different tables. However, using your suggestion I reworked the measure as follows:

```
Actual Spend at Forecasting Period:=CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Finance Actuals'[Amount] ),
    FILTER (
        ALLSELECTED ( 'Finance Period' ),
        'Finance Period'[Fiscal_Date_Key] <= MAX ( 'Finance Period'[Fiscal_Date_Key] )
    ),
    FILTER (
        ALL('Finance Calculated Data Snapshot Date'),
        'Finance Calculated Data Snapshot Date'[Calculated_Date_Key]
            <= MAX ( 'Finance Forecasting Period'[Calculated_Date_Key] )
    )
)
```

This worked and achieved the result I was hoping for, so thanks for the suggestion. However, I'm still curious as to what you were specifically suggesting with

> Try moving the ALL function inside your second FILTER function since
>   that's where it needs to be applied.

Comment: Yes, this is essentially what I was suggesting. There are probably a few variations that would work, but it's difficult to try to write DAX when I don't have the exact tables and relations visible to me.